# Is there a complete react-native Component API

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

At the top of my new react native app some boilerplate code is created

```
export default class App extends Component < {} > {
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Within the Learn the Basics webpage of the React Native Documentation there is a section on [Component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#components). Within this section it mentions

> A component can be pretty simple - the only thing that's required is a
>   render function...

I can't see in the API list an entry for `Component`. I presume this `Component` has the same idea as `Object` in Java as the base class for everything. 
Java's `Object` class provides some methods such as `toString()`.

I would like to know :

- Is my presumption correct?
- Is there a weblink to documentation somewhere that details the full
  api for `Component`?
- What else provided by react native, that isn't my own custom code, can be put inside my `App`
  class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can read about React Components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). React-Native utilizes React architecture.
2. Component is a module of your app that has a particular functionality. On the left sidebar [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) you can see a section called "Components" These are the default React-Native components. You can create other components, needed in your app by using those components. Examples of how the components could look or be created are components of Expo SDK and React-Native-Elements component library.

   Through this link you can view all of React-Native and Expo components on your device using Expo app: https://expo.io/@community/native-component-list
3. Your custom components / components of other libraries that you would like to render (put them in return statement, wrapped with parenthesis, like `return (<Text>Hello World</Text>);`.

   Plus anything that is related to rendering your screen could also be put inside the render method, but outside the return statement. For example, state / props destructuring, conditional rendering (if something is true - show this view, else show this view) and so forth.

Comment: Aaah, the penny drops. The base Component comes from React. That was the bit I missed. Thanks.